# How to get a collection from the ViewModel to the View?

Tags: c#, mvvm, xamarin.forms

I have an `ObservableCollection` of objects that gets stored in the `ViewModel` and for each object I want to add a `BoxView` to my `View`.  I plan to build the `BoxViews` in the XAML code behind to keep it separate from the business logic.  My problem is that I cannot figure out the correct way to access the collection in the `ViewModel` from the `View`.  Is there a way to bind a collection variable in the `View` to the one in the `ViewModel`, or maybe someone knows a better way to implement something like this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
public partial class MyPage
{
    private MyViewModel _viewModel;
    public MyPage()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    protected override void OnBindingContextChanged()
    {
        base.OnBindingContextChanged();
        _viewModel = BindingContext as MyViewModel;
        var collection = _viewModel.MyCollection;
    }

}
```

Comment: This works, it returns my ViewModel collection correctly however the OnBindingContextChanged() method is called after the screen is drawn so I can't add boxviews at this point.  Any suggestions?

Comment: If you know that your collection is already filled, you can go @Idev way. And create your UI in code-behind constructor.

Answer (score 1):

You should use a `ListView` control to do this and bind your view model collection to the `ItemsSource` property of the `ListView` using `{Binding}` syntax. You can see an example of this in the [documentation](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/xamarin-forms/user-interface/listview/data-and-databinding/#Data_Binding).

Do not forget to set the `BindingContext` to the instance of your `ViewModel` class.

To define how each individual item should be displayed, you will need to declare a `ItemTemplate`. A simple example based on your requirements would be:

```
<ListView x:Name="MyList" ItemsSource="{Binding Data}">
   <ListView.ItemTemplate>
      <DataTemplate>
         <BoxView />
      </DataTemplate>
   </ListView.ItemTemplate>
</ListView>
```

To access individual properties of your list items you can use `{Binding}` inside the `DataTemplate`. For example to bind a `Name` property you would do something like:

```
<ListView x:Name="MyList" ItemsSource="{Binding Data}">
   <ListView.ItemTemplate>
      <DataTemplate>
         <Label Text="{Binding Name}" />
      </DataTemplate>
   </ListView.ItemTemplate>
</ListView>
```

Comment: I want to create each BoxView's dimensions based on each object's data from the Collection (it's purely graphical, no information will be displayed).  I could bind the Collection to a ListView and set IsVisible = false, but that seems incorrect.

Comment: You can try binding to the `HeightRequest` and `WidthRequest` properties, but I am not sure how it will work in a list scenario. You will definitely have to set `HasUnevenRows` property to `true`.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to access the data in code behind using mvvm you can do something like this :

```
 vm = new YourViewModel(optionalParameter);
 BindingContext = vm;
 yourListView.ItemsSource = theDataYouWantToPersist;
```

This is what worked for me. If you need more details please provide more details and code.