# How can I access a property from a ViewModel to a ButtonClickEvent which is inside the CodeBehind of Xaml View?

Tags: xaml, xamarin, xamarin.forms

I want to access the properties created in ViewModel to the xaml code behind file. Please have a look at the attached screenshot for better understanding on my question.

[***Please Click Here to View the Screenshot of my Xaml code***](https://i.stack.imgur.com/elsFs.jpg)

[***Click Here for the Properties code***](https://i.stack.imgur.com/c58AF.jpg)

I have bind the "EntryText" property to an Entry field and "LblText" property to a Label. So, now I just want to transfer the value of Entry to the Label on a button click event.

Comment: You have got the right idea, just bind your label to the text property and on button click set the value of LblText to that of the entry. You can set the LblText default value to "Enter your name" for initial case.

Comment: Sorry, I just got your question, you can bind a command to your button click event. You can place the command in your viewmodel and access your other properties there.

Comment: I'm able to achieve the result by binding a command to the button click. But I just want to know if there is any way of achieving the same result using the button click event. I meant, is there any way to access the LblText property and EntryText property inside the ButtonClickEvent?

Answer (score 2):

You're on the right track, just need to search slightly differently. 
There's multiple ways of doing this. I will tell you the simplest way since that's also suggested in the [Xamarin Official Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/user-interface/button). So your Xaml code will look like this

```
<ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             x:Class="ButtonDemos.BasicButtonClickPage"
             Title="Basic Button Click">
    <StackLayout>
        <Label x:Name="label"
               Text="Click the Button below"
               FontSize="Large"
               VerticalOptions="CenterAndExpand"
               HorizontalOptions="Center" />
        <Button Text="Click to Rotate Text!"
                VerticalOptions="CenterAndExpand"
                HorizontalOptions="Center"
                Clicked="OnButtonClicked" />
    </StackLayout>
</ContentPage>
```

And your C# file would look like this

```
public partial class BasicButtonClickPage : ContentPage
{
    public BasicButtonClickPage ()
    {
        InitializeComponent ();
    }

    async void OnButtonClicked(object sender, EventArgs args)
    {
        await label.RelRotateTo(360, 1000);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use code-behind to invoke a method in the view model. So in that method, you can change the LblText. Refer below code.

```
<Button x:Name="btn1" Clicked="btnClicked" />
```

In code-behide

```
private void btnClicked(object sender, EventArgs e){

   _viewModel.ChangeLabelText();

}
```

In the View Model

```
public void ChangeLabelText() {

   LblText = EntryText;

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the page's BindingContext and cast it to your model. And, then access the property from there.

```
var myModel = this.BindingContext as MainPageProperties;
if(myModel!=null)
{
    //Access your property here!
    var text = myModel.LblText;
}
```

Comment: You better get bindingContext in the method `OnBindingContextChanged()`: [https://stackoverflow.com/a/48749330/5941852](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48749330/5941852)